# Contextual type 'Int' cannot be used with array literal

Tags: swift, for-loop

The code I'm trying to perform will return the largest product of adjacent members in an array. 
Here is my code:

```
func adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray: [Int]) -> Int {
    var multiplierArray = [Int?]()

    for i in 0...(inputArray.count-1) {
        multiplierArray.append([inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1]])
       }
    return multiplierArray.max()
}
```

I'm getting the error described in the title on the line:

```
multiplierArray.append([inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1]])
```

I'm also getting another error: missing argument for parameter 'by' in call
on the line:

```
return multiplierArray.max()
```

Any help is appreciated,and if there's an error in the formatting or anything else about this question please do not hesitate to correct me!

Comment: You need add an `Int`  not a `Int` array so change this line `multiplierArray.append([inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1]])` by this one 
 `multiplierArray.append(inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1])`

Comment: The error is perfectly self-explanatory.

Comment: also change this `var multiplierArray = [Int?]()` by this `var multiplierArray : [Int] = []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray: [Int]) -> Int {
    var multiplierArray = [Int]()

    for i in 0...(inputArray.count-1) {
        multiplierArray.append(inputArray[i] * inputArray[i+1])
    }
    return multiplierArray.max()!
}
```

**EDIT:**

Fix to index out of range :)

```
func adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray: [Int]) -> Int {
    var multiplierArray = [Int]()

    for i in 0...(inputArray.count - 2) {
        multiplierArray.append(inputArray[i] * inputArray[i+1])
    }
    return multiplierArray.max()!
}
```

Issue in your code was that u were iterating over every element in array and you were multiplying the number with its adjacent number in the array. When you reach the last element and you try to access the next element without check it goes out of array.

Comment: Thank you so much! When I ran the code, all previous errors in the question were fixed. When ran though, the return was a fatal error due to the index being out of range. I had experienced that error before with another approach to this code. If it wouldn't be too much a hassle, could you provide a suggestion to this error? Once again, thanks!

Comment: @colin-brennan : Gimme a minute

Comment: @colin-brennan : Always welcome buddy :) Please consider accepting the answer if it helped